# linked ELF file contains no symbols

Tags: gcc, linker, avr

I compiled my AVR C source-code to object files. These objects contain debug symbols:

`~ avr-nm code.c.o: 
00000000 T ClockInit32MhzXtal
00000000 T CopyDataToSensors
00000000 T FindSensors
         U I2CInitMaster
00000000 T PC_UsartInit
00000000 T ReadFromSensorSettings
00000000 T ResetAndAlignSampleClock
00000000 T SampleClockTimerInit
00000000 T SendDataToPC
...`

When linking all files into a single file, these symbols seem to be lost although I specified the -g option:

`~ /usr/local/bin/avr-gcc  -O1 -lm -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-g -std=gnu99 -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -g -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -DF_CPU=32000000 -mmcu=atxmega128a1u file1.c.o file2.c.o  -o program.elf
/usr/local/opt/avr-binutils/bin/avr-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol arch_paths_first; defaulting to 0000000000000000
~ avr-nm program.elf
avr-nm: program.elf: no symbols`

How can this be? Shouldn't the linker create a new symbol table with debug info in the linked file?

`avr-gcc: gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC)
avr-ld:  GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.25`

Comment: Solved by `clawson` at avrfreaks.net . `-Wl,search_paths_first` is misinterpreted as `-Wl,se` and `arch_paths_first` because the non-existance of the `search_paths_first` option in avr-ld. This option was automatically added by a misconfigured CMake config.  http://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/1985241#comment-1985241

Comment: You should probably delete (unlikely this will help someone else) or answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-Wl,-search_paths_first` flag was added by CLion. It is however no valid avr-gcc flag but a typical OS X flag. The compiler tried to find the first existing match which was `-Wl,-s`. I.e. Strip symbols.